# Helm: when to push a chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I don't quite to figure out when a helm chart has to be pushed on a `chartmuseum` or any other repo.

I mean:

- each time an app version changes, regardless of whether internal resources and values have not changed? For example, a new image version has changed.
- or each time chart handles a new (or remove, or change) resource, or add a new value...?

I hope I've explained so well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is up to chart maintainers to push chart in any of that cases. More info about [charts and verioning](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#charts-and-versioning).

In your case, you will:

- change `appVersion` field in [Chart.yaml file](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#the-chartyaml-file) when the app image changes
- change `version` field in [Chart.yaml file](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#the-chartyaml-file) when chart resources are modified.

Make sure you follow [SemVer 2](https://semver.org/) standard when modifying any of those.